# How can i login to stackoverflow site with Scrapy python

Tags: python, scrapy

I have just started learning scrapy and i want to try some prasing with python and Scrapy.
I am thinking of getting the list of questions from specific tags, which i have posted, and then parse them on SO.

But i am not sure how can i log with open id and Scrapy.

Can some please guide me with this on which url i have to submit the data because when i will type the openid then site gets transfered to openid url so how can i enter password there

Comment: I would use [Stack Exchange API](https://api.stackexchange.com/) for that (even if it's not exactly what you asked for). For example, [this query](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/top-user-questions-in-tags#order=desc&sort=activity&filter=default&site=stackoverflow&run=true) returns the top 30 questions a user has asked with the given tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [your RSS feed](https://stackoverflow.com/feeds/user/1819817) (basically xml).

One other way I can think of is to:

```
Login normally in browser
export cookies to file
use that file in script
```

I can think of a situation where `fanatic` badge would become less valued. Because, then people would simply schedule cron on their server to visit SO every day! So, I advice not doing anything of this sort.

Comment: I am very weak in cookies things. is there any tutorail which can tell me how to use cookies with scrapy

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#using-formrequest-from-response-to-simulate-a-user-login) is a good example how to simulate a user login request using scrapy.